# "About" or "About us"? "Contact" or "Contact us"? "Services" or "Our services"?

Tags: url, title, page

There are about 5-10 most basic pages that some would say it's a best practice to include them in many sites. These are, for example:

*About us*, *Contact us*, *Our services*, *Privacy policy*, *Portfolio*, and some would even add *Guestbook* and *Recommendations* (though these two are far less admired then they once was).

Have you ever came across any recommendation from the major search engines, or alternatively, any recommendation from any SEOer to build the aliases (permalinks) of these pages in a certain way? For example, build the alias as "About" instead of "About us" and vice versa, or build it as "Contact" instead of "Contact us" respectively?

My personal reason says - "The shortest within context is generally the better", though I would like to know what are your stances and experience on this.

Comment: It doesn't matter at all

Comment: @JohnConde is exactly right. After nearly two decades, I think the search engines have this one figured out. Do not worry about it. Just be traditional and do not replace Contact Us with Hollar At Me or About US with What Wees Bee Doing. I have seen this.

Comment: "Guestbook" - Hhhmm, trying to think when I last saw a guestbook on a site ...?!

Comment: Indeed it's hard to find but I saw it a few days ago in the site of the neoceltic band "Omnia"...

Answer (score 5):

Proper selection of title / url permalink does make a difference to your seo rankings as the title / url put a strong emphasis on what the content of the page looks like and it should ideally match the content of your page as crawler is intelligent enough to identify the title you are giving to your page and content on that page.

These matters for most of your pages but for the cases you have specified it does not make a lot of sense. It can be both about / about-us.

The title is also important for showcasing your content in **google's search   result snippet**. As this would be what user will see in result when your page comes in search result.

So title should ideally be About {Your Company Name}. Contact | {Your company name}. Url permalink should be like:

example.com/contact or example.com/contact-us as your company or site name is already represented by your domain.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's doesn't matter for SEO. Search engine want you to offer unique and relevant content on your site

Comment: This isn't a very useful answer

Comment: This isn't an answer at all and should be posted as a coment.

Answer (score 0):

So, those are pronouns.

A **pronoun** (I, me, he, she, herself, you, it, that, they, each, few, many, who, whoever, whose, someone, everybody, etc.) is a word that takes the place of a noun.

People who are linguists or professors of languages advise speakers not to use pronoun - noun or noun - pronoun types of words. So, linguistically, the correct way to use it is without "us" or "our" or whatever.

That's the only thing about it. It doesn't matter for a link, it doesn't matter for SEO. It's just better/more fluent or by-the-book reading / writing.